# Mostrar datos en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos tablas (`alumnos` y `Colegiaturas`) pero quisiera poder mostrar los pagos mensuales que ha realizado cada alumno omitiendo los meses que no ha pagado, Ejemplo:

```
Alumno   Enero   Febrero   Marzo
Carlos   Si       X        Si
Luis     Si       Si       X
Andres   Si       Si       Si
```

Este es el código de mi vista:

```
@foreach ($alumnos as $alumno)  
< tr>  
    < td>< strong>{{$alumno->nombres}} </strong>  
          @foreach($colegiaturas as $colegiatura)  
                 @if($colegiatura->alumno->nombres==$alumno->nombres)  
                 <td>{{$colegiatura->mes->nombre}}</td>  
                @endif  
            @endforeach  
    < /td>  
    < /tr>  
@endforeach
```

Y el de mi controlador es este:

```
public function consultagrado(Request $request)  
  {  
    $meses=array("Inscripción", "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Graduación");  
    $carreras=Carrera::selectRaw('CONCAT(grado, " ", nombre) as nombres, id')
    ->lists('nombres', 'id');  
    if ($request->carrera_id){
    $alumnos=alumno::buscar($request->carrera_id)->get();  
    $colegiaturas= colegiatura::orderby('mes_id','ASC')->get();  
    $groupcolegiaturas=$alumnos->groupby('nombres');  
    }  
    else {  
      {  
        $alumnos=alumno::Search($request->nombres)->get();  
        $colegiaturas= colegiatura::orderby('mes_id','ASC')->get();  
        $groupcolegiaturas=$alumnos->groupby('nombres');  
      }  
    }  

    return view('admin.colegiaturas.consultagrado', compact ('colegiaturas', 'groupcolegiaturas', 'alumnos', 'carreras', 'meses'));  
  }
```

Comment: Incluye algo de código, sino es bien difícil de que alguien lo haga por ti. Esto para saber como estás pensado en resolver el problema

Comment: Agrega el código que llevas hecho para poder ayudarte.